# Copy/paste results from Cube Browser in SSMS 2017

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, ssas, ssms-2017

On my SSMS 2008 R2, whenever I browse a cube through SSAS, I can easily select all my results (Ctrl+A) and copy/paste it (Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V) into a Excel spreadsheet. As so (notice how all the content gets highlighted):

[image]

When I attempt the same thing with SSM 2017, none of this works. I researched the problem; however, it appears as though this functionality got removed. Or is it just me?

(I know that I can connect my Excel spreadsheet to my source and do all my manipulations there, but since I always work on SSMS, it's easier if I can keep using it without opening an Excel file. Especially, since I don't always need to do some comparisons with a spreadsheet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of of quirks of SSMS. The Browse Cube option does not allow you to copy the results.

BUT, there is a work-around. From your Browse Cube screen, click the 'Design Mode' to get the actual MDX query

[image]

Now, open a new MDX query editor Window

[image]

In this editor, paste you MDX query and execute it.

Now, you should be able to copy the results.

[image]